# Browser enlarges image without any obvious reason

Tags: html, css

I created an image with size of 300px/200px. I've put it on the site with  `img` selector and for some bizarre reasons, browser enlarges it. The code is simple:

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <img src="picture.jpg">
    </body>
</html>
```

It must be enlarged by the browser, but why the heck? Any ideas?
([Comparison demo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o3Ev.png))
On the screenshot you can see the comparison of how this image should look and how it looks in browser. Don't pay attention to names, I changed name in code here for clarity.

Comment: Wild speculation: One of the two programs has a zoom level set to something other than 100%

Comment: Please refer to the tips here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp
"...without these attributes (height & width), the browser does not know the size of the image, and cannot reserve the appropriate space to it."

Answer (score 0):

Give it height and width like this:

```
<img src="picture.jpg" width=300 height=200>
```